# How to Loop NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();

Tags: navigation

I want to loop my NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); command until I have reached a specific page (called MainPage) in my back stack. How do I check and condition whether or not that page has been reached by removing all elements in the stack before it.
Sometimes, for that page to be reached, I need to loop `RemoveBackEntry();` twice or thrice until that page is reached... so on.

Step 1: I want it to first check how many places behind that the "MainPage" exists in the backstack...say 'n' places.
step 2: Then I want to run the `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` n-1 times so that I can end up on MainPage.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!!

[How Can I remove backstack till the required pagename in Wp7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294734/how-can-i-remove-backstack-till-the-required-pagename-in-wp7-1/10354820#10354820)

while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)

{

```
if (NavigationService.BackStack.First().Source.OriginalString == "/C.xaml")
        {
            break;
        }
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

}

This worked for me, its simpler than the method I had wanted to use!!